# If $\sum n, \frac{\sqrt{10}}{3}\sum n^2, \sum n^3$ are in geometric progression, then find the value of n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

If $\sum n, \frac{\sqrt{10}}{3}\sum n^2, \sum n^3$ are in geometric progression, then find the value of n?

*I had initially typed the question incorrectly which was the sole reason why I couldn't solve it. Have corrected it now.*

The options given for 'n'are: 3,4,2,6

Comment: a $\Sigma$ is missing

Comment: Well, exactly this question has been asked in my textbook.

Comment: what does your summation sum over? Is the first term $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ or is it $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ where $x_i$ is something that you didn't type? Remark: your second term is irrational.

Comment: The summation means sum till n terms, like 1+2+3+4+...+n

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question Please format the question properly, and do not type part of the question in the title without typing it again in the body. As pointed out already, there probably is a mistake in the question as it currently is, given that the 1st, 3rd and 4th terms are integers, while the 2nd is irrational.

Comment: I, too, felt the same. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: there is a typo somewhere, in any case the relation of $\frac{\sum_{i}^{n}n^3}{\sum_{i}^{n}n^2}=\frac{3n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}=q$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the problem is to find $n$ such that 
$$a_1=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n i}\qquad a_2=\frac {10}{\sqrt 3}\qquad a_3=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}\qquad a_4=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n i^3}$$ be in geometric progression.

Considering $$\frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{a_4}{a_3}\implies \frac{10 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{n (n+1)}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} n (n+1)}{\sqrt{n (n+1) (2 n+1)}}$$ that is to say $${10 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{n(n+1)}{\sqrt{2n+1} }$$ which is effectively satisfied for $n=4$.

Comment: Why take square root of sums?

Comment: @hypergeometric. My answer was for the first version of the question (which changed).

Comment: I see. Interestingly the answer for $n$ is the same for both cases!

Answer (score 0):

Use the notation $\displaystyle\sigma_m=\sum_{r=1}^n r^m$.

Given the following GP:
$$\begin{align}
a_1&=\sigma_1\tag{1}\\
a_2&=\frac{\sqrt{10}}3\sigma_2=\frac{\sqrt{10}}3\bigg(\frac {2n+1}3\sigma_1\bigg)\tag{2}\\
a_3&=\sigma_3=\sigma_1^2\tag{3}\\
r^2=\frac {(3)}{(1)}=\bigg(\frac {(2)}{(1)}\bigg)^2:\\
r^2=\quad\sigma_1=\frac {n(n+1)}2&=\frac {10}{81}(2n+1)^2\\
81n(n+1)&=20(4n^2+4n+1)\\
n^2+n-20&=0\\
(n+5)(n-4)&=0\\
\color{red}n&\color{red}{=4}
\end{align}$$

---

The GP is 
$$\begin{align}
a_1&=\qquad \;\; 1\; +2\; +3\; +4&&=10\\
a_2&=\frac {\sqrt{10}}3\big(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2\big)=\frac{\sqrt{10}}3 (30)&&=10\sqrt{10}\\
a_3&=\qquad\  1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3&&=100
\end{align}$$
with common ratio $r=\sqrt{10}$.